# Android Simple facebook SDK birthday returns null

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

I am creating a new facebook app on https://developers.facebook.com/, it  returns null birthday while I am using the credential(FB id and namespace) of my old facebook app its working fine. I am not able to figure out the issue, please help...

```
Permission[] permissions = new Permission[] {
                Permission.PUBLIC_PROFILE,
                Permission.USER_BIRTHDAY,
                Permission.USER_EDUCATION_HISTORY,
                Permission.USER_LOCATION,
                Permission.EMAIL,
                Permission.USER_WORK_HISTORY
        };
SimpleFacebookConfiguration configuration = new SimpleFacebookConfiguration.Builder()
       .setAppId(APP_ID)
       .setNamespace(APP_NAMESPACE)
       .setPermissions(permissions)
       .build();
SimpleFacebook.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

and then call simpleFacebook.login()

Comment: can you please provide us some more information like some code snippets or so?

Comment: @uniking I have post some code please check

Comment: @user1041858 any luck??